# What is the frequency of AUM

Tags: om

Every mantra begins with the word ॐ (Aum/Om).
ॐ itself is considered a mantra in Ayurveda

does anyone knows what is the frequency of AUM(ॐ)

Comment: Scientific speculations are off-topic.

Comment: can you explain bit how this is off-topic does our books doesn't contain text that sound scientific? I believe Aum is hinduism symbol we should know all details

Comment: Please read - https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/862/how-should-we-handle-answers-with-partial-scientific-speculation-and-or-partial

Comment: Okay @Vivikta I will follow this guideline

Comment: what should i do with this post simply just delete it?

Comment: It's Your choice.

Comment: What do you mean by frequency here?

Comment: @VipanKumar No need to delete the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sound of OM when chanted, vibrates at the frequency of 432 Hz which is the same vibration frequency found throughout everything in nature. when is chanted properly

The sound of AUM is a reflection of the “trinity” that is often referred to in spiritual traditions, and represents the 3 divisions of time (waking, dreaming, and deep sleep)

1. Ah – represents creation/waking/gross/conscious and connects with the lower part of the body.
2. Ooh represents preservation/dreaming/subtle and connects the middle part of the body.
3. Mm represents liberation/deep sleep/causal and affects the upper part of the body.

so proper sound is `Ahooohmmmmmm`

Comment: you just google any instrument how can i test it check

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Please take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. Answers here must be backed-up with "authoritative sources/references". Kindly visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). For more info please do visit: [the HSE Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help). Have an enriching journey!!

Comment: Also, scientific speculations are off-topic. In here, it is not recommended to either ask such scientific speculation questions, neither answer them, if asked.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312153393_SCIENTIFIC_ANALYSIS_OF_AUM_MANTRA_IN_KNOWING_SELF

Comment: @Mantra K The paper you posted was written by a university student who studies management, not Science, a very bad source, also anyone can send stuff on researchgate.net, try citing a peer-reviewed source.

Comment: A proper reading of the research paper you cited will tell, that it's pseudo scientific jugglery by a college level student, published by a tier 10 level publication with no impact factor whatsoever. This research paper is neither scientific nor religious. This is why Indian research is rarely praised internationally. I'd suggest you to read high quality research, please. :)